# md-tabs Using code to goto a tab in angular 2 material design

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular2 to create an application i which i need to navigate between tabs using a button present inside the tabs.

my html is as the following :

```
<md-tab-group>
<md-tab label="one">
   <button md-raised-button>Navigate to Two</button>
   <button md-raised-button>Navigate to Three</button>
</md-tab label>
<md-tab label="two">
</md-tab label>
<md-tab label="three"> 
</md-tab label>
</md-tab-group>
```

So,when i click the navigate to three it should take me to the tab name three

I am using the Angular2 material design for this example can anyone know to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be achieved using **selectedIndex** input variable using the below code

```
<md-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1 
  <button (click)="clickMe()"> click me to go to tab 2 </button>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

and your typescript code will be

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tabs-sample',
  templateUrl: './tabsSample.html',
})
export class TabsSample {
  selectedIndex:number=0;
  clickMe(){
    this.selectedIndex=1;
  }

}
```

Update 1: Based on comment.

You can use the **selectedIndexChange** method to fix that error as below

```
<md-tab-group  (selectedIndexChange)="selectedIndexChange($event)" 
               [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">

</md-tab-group>
```

and your code will have

```
selectedIndexChange(val :number ){
    this.selectedIndex=val;
  }
```

Updated in the plunk as well.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/JPX0HBvXj8JyqfZdRsFF?p=preview)**

Comment: when i perform the button click for the second time i am not able to navigate between the pages

Answer (score 2):

you want to use the [Angular Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

try this:

**in your html**

```
<md-tab-group>
<md-tab label="one">
   <button md-raised-button (click)="goToTwo()">Navigate to Two</button>
   <button md-raised-button (click)="goToThree()">Navigate to Three</button>
</md-tab label>
</md-tab-group>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**inside your component class**

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

goToTwo() {
  this.router.navigate(['two'])
}

goToThree(){
  this.router.navigate(['three'])
}
```

don't forget to import the Router in your component

`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

**in your module**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/two',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent,
  },
  { path: 'three', component: ThreeComponent }
];
...

imports: [
  ...,
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
],
```

and of course create `TwoComponent` and `ThreeComponent`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is by creating components i don't want this kind of solution, I need to route between tabs in a single page

Comment: Ok then you might need to take a look at [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) and/or `ng-content`.